# Local global principle over infinite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ which is not algebraically closed

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, tate-shafarevich-groups

Let $A$ be an algebraic variety over a field $K$, which is **finite** extension of $ \Bbb{Q}$.
We say local global principle holds if $A(K_v) \neq \emptyset$ implies $A(K) \neq  \emptyset$, where $K_v$ is the completion of $K$ at a place $v$.If $A$ is genus $0$ curve, this principle holds. But when genus is $1$ or more, this principle does not hold in general and we measure the failure by items, for example, if $A$ is abelian variety, we often use Tate Shafarevich group.

But what about the case of $K$ is a **infinite** extension of $ \Bbb{Q}$, which is not algebraically closed field, for example, $ K=\Bbb{Q}(ζ_{p^{∞}})$ ?.
Are there any known results about the local global principle over a **infinite** extension of $ \Bbb{Q}$, which is not algebraically closed field ?

Comment: There are results for fields over which every algeraic variety satisfies some sort of local-global principle for rational points. For example, over so-called pseudo-algebraically closed fields, every (geometrically integral) variety has a rational point, so that is in a sense a trivial lgp. Over pseudo-real closed fields, the "completions" are all algebraically closed or real closed, and a variety has a rational point if it has one over each of these. And so on. Many algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ have these properties.

Comment: Thank you for reaction, Then non 'pseudo-algebraically closed field(PAC)' is our interest, for example, $ \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{p^{∞}})$ may not be PAC.